# Carrierwave processed images not uploading to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have Carrierwave uploading images just fine to S3 buckets. However if I use RMagick to process thumbnails, the files only get saved to public tmp locally. Commenting out the process method creates the original and thumb files on S3 (of course the thumb is not processed). Not sure why the processing is stopping right after writing to local tmp. Code below:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [32, 32]
  end
end
```

Rails 3.2.5
Fog 1.3.1
Rmagick 2.13.1
Carrierwave 0.6.2
Carrierwave-mongoid 0.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use minimagick:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
end
```

For thumb version I recommend you that you use `resize_to_fill` method like sth:

```
version :thumb do
   process :resize_to_fill => [32, 32]
   process :convert => :png
 end
```

you can also use a unique token for each image:

```
def filename
     @name ||= "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
   end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.uuid)
  end
```

you must ensure that your connection with your bucket is correct in the confidential file `config/initializers/fog.rb` sth like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'your_key',
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'your_secret_key',
    :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }

  config.fog_directory = 'your_bucket_here'
  config.fog_public = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'} 
end
```