# Carrierwave processed images not uploading to AWS S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, sidekiq

Similar problem to this question but the solution provided did not fix my problem. [Carrierwave processed images not uploading to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069411/carrierwave-processed-images-not-uploading-to-s3)

Using Railscast #383 as basis for code: http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3

The image is successfully uploaded to S3 using carrierwave_direct.  I want to process the images in the background with sidekiq and then upload to S3.

The sidekiq worker completes the image processing without error but the processed images (:thumb and :large) are stored locally in the public/uploads folder.

Any idea why the processed images are not being uploaded to S3?

Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

storage :fog

include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
process :set_content_type

include Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper
include Sprockets::Helpers::IsolatedHelper

version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
end

version :large do
  process :resize_to_limit => [600, 400]
end

def extension_white_list
   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
end
end
```

Model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible  :name, :image, :remote_image_url, :user_id
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

belongs_to :user

after_commit :enqueue_image, :on => :create

has_many :comments, as: :commentable

def image_name
        File.basename(image.path || image.filename) if image
end

def enqueue_image
    ImageWorker.perform_async(id, key) if key.present?
end

class ImageWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    sidekiq_options retry: false

        def perform(id, key)
          photo = Photo.find(id)
          photo.key = key
          photo.remote_image_url = photo.image.direct_fog_url(with_path: true)
          photo.save!
        end
    end

end
```

PhotoController

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

 def index
  @photos = Photo.all
  @uploader = Photo.new.image
  @uploader.success_action_redirect = new_photo_url
 end
```

View

```
.
. 
.
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :image %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Photo" %></p>
<% end %>
```

initializers/carrierwave.rb

```
 CarrierWave.configure do |config|
   config.fog_credentials = {
    provider: "AWS",
    aws_access_key_id: ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
end
```

initializers/fog.rb *added this based on the response to the question linked above

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',
    :aws_access_key_id      => ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
    :aws_secret_access_key  => ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"],
   :region                 => 'us-east-1'
  }

 config.fog_directory = ENV["AWS_S3_BUCKET"]
 config.fog_public = true
 config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=315576000'} 
end
```

Comment: what does your config/initializers/carrierwave.rb look like?

Comment: Try renaming your bucket to something with no dashes undersoces or numbers, eg. `myawesomewebsitedotcom`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my uploaders folder I had copied my original uploader and renamed it 'image_uploader_file.rb'. I then modified the origial version 'image_uploader.rb' to use fog and S3.  I assumed that carrierwave would only use 'image_uploader.rb' but it appears that it loaded both files.  The old version used local storage so that is where carrierwave stored the images.  Once I deleted 'image_uploader_file.rb' the processed images were properly uploaded to S3.